# Can websites send WhatsApp messages without my permission through the WhatsApp API?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I want to know if it is possible for websites to send messages through my WhatsApp without my permission. I read about the WhatsApp API, but I haven't done much PHP so it did not make much sense to me.

Is it also possible for a website to view my contacts, as well as post messages to existing chats that I have not deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

It no way possible can they do this with out having you security token (Lets call it your login credentials).
The PHP API you saw is an unofficial API and requires logging in when starting it up.

**What can a website do?**

There is something called WhatsApp URI which lets websites build a custom link that upon pressing will redirect you to WhatsApp so you can share their content ([See more here](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012)).

Comment: Can they send messages to a contact that I did not select?

Comment: @Don Nope! not unless they hacked your phone/obtained your credentials.

Comment: How can one obtain my credentials...sorry if this is a long explanation.

Comment: You gave them out or they hacked your phone.

Comment: Can this be done remotely?

Comment: If they have a virus on your phone - yes.

Comment: Your answer was helpful.

Comment: @Don You are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

In order to use your WhatsApp account, they'll need your username and password. If they have that, then yes it's possible. This is one of the many reasons you shouldn't have the same password for multiple services.

With your credentials, they can do anything and access any service available to a normally logged-in user -including view contacts.